# How to add values to another Category in XML for Gantt Chart in SAP?

Tags: xml, charts, abap, gantt-chart, sap-gui

I am working on a Gantt Chart following [this post](http://scn.sap.com/thread/1919275) and I am almost ready but I have the following problem.

The code below, shows me the Gantt Chart that I have designed with ChartDesigner, but it presents all of the boxes only in Category 1! How can I make that the boxes under the Category2 (in the code below) appear in Category 2?

```
APPEND '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' TO lt_data_text.
APPEND '<ChartData> ' TO lt_data_text.

APPEND '<Categories><Category >Category1</Category></Categories>' TO lt_data_text.
APPEND '<Series customizing="Series1">' TO lt_data_text.
APPEND '<Point>' TO lt_data_text.
APPEND '<Value type="time">20000301</Value>' TO lt_data_text.
APPEND '<Value type="time">20000305</Value>' TO lt_data_text.
APPEND '<Value type="time">20000310</Value>' TO lt_data_text.
APPEND '<Value type="time">20000319</Value>' TO lt_data_text.
APPEND '</Point>' TO lt_data_text.
APPEND '</Series>' TO lt_data_text.


APPEND '<Categories><Category >Category2</Category></Categories>' TO lt_data_text.
APPEND '<Series customizing="Series2" >' TO lt_data_text.
APPEND '<Point>' TO lt_data_text.
APPEND '<Value type="time">20000310</Value>' TO lt_data_text.
APPEND '<Value type="time">20000315</Value>' TO lt_data_text.
APPEND '<Value type="time">20000320</Value>' TO lt_data_text.
APPEND '<Value type="time">20000329</Value>' TO lt_data_text.
APPEND '</Point>' TO lt_data_text.
APPEND '</Series>' TO lt_data_text.

APPEND '</ChartData>' TO lt_data_text.
```

Comment: This appending looks monstrous. At least consider creating a macro for that.

Answer (score 0):

remove line:

```
APPEND '<Categories><Category >Category2</Category></Categories>' TO lt_data_text.
```

change line:

```
APPEND '<Categories><Category>Category1</Category></Categories>' TO lt_data_text.
```

to following

```
APPEND '<Categories><Category>Category1</Category><Category>Category2</Category></Categories>' TO lt_data_text.
```

should work i guess